# Faster way to process calculations on very large data frames

Tags: r

I am working with several data frames that are all 61,143 rows and 9,864 columns. That makes just over 600 million values in each data frame. This makes any calculation on the data frame extremely slow - several hours. For example:

```
OBS    61143 obs. of 9864 variables

OBS.MAX <- apply(OBS, 1, max)
```

These values were originally derived from a netcdf file that I then converted from a raster brick to a data frame. Is there any quicker way calculations like the above could be done? Is working within a data frame like this inefficient?

Comment: 600 million values is not that big. R can run operations on datasets with 60 millions rows and 10 columns in a few seconds. The problem is that data.frames are column-oriented. Processing one massive column is faster than processing many smaller columns. Is there a natural way to reshape your data?

Comment: Use functions that vectorize the operation, such as `do.call(pmax, OBS)`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I could reshape the data, but am not sure what options are open that would make processing much quicker. What exactly does vectorizing the operation do?

Comment: It avoids loops with many function calls, which is slow in R. Also, `apply` calls `as.matrix` as a first step. You don't want to do this with larger data as it is a quite costly operation.

Comment: 1. Use a matrix. row-wise operations on data frames are slow (which is why apply converts it to a matrix anyway, but *each time you run it*). 2. Use fast commodity functions such as `rowMax(OBS)`.

Comment: apply is the slowest function created by mankind. Check the matrixStats package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always easier to talk with some example data

```
library(raster)
b <- brick(ncol=245, nrow=250, nl=9864)
v <- matrix(rep(1:ncell(b), nlayers(b)), ncol=nlayers(b))
values(b) <- v
bb <- writeRaster(b, "test.nc", overwrite=TRUE)
d <- data.frame(v)
```

Now I get the following

```
# matrix 
system.time(apply(v, 1, max))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  10.68    0.79   11.46 

# data.frame
system.time(apply(d, 1, max))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  20.48    0.61   21.11 

# RasterBrick (values in memory)
system.time(max(b))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   6.72    0.29    7.00 

system.time(calc(b, max))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  16.76    0.33   17.11 

# RasterBrick (values on disk)
system.time(max(bb))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  19.25    8.43   27.70 

system.time(calc(bb, max))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  22.69    5.92   28.62
```

Based on this I would use the `RasterBrick` and `max` (or `calc` more generally) because extracting the values from file also takes time

```
system.time( values(bb))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  21.91    5.28   27.18
```

But a lot depends on your workflow --- how many computations per data set, for example. 
These computations take a while, but you report "several hours" of computation. That suggest that the problem is in the function you are applying. Perhaps you need to rewrite these.